# Is it possible to edit read-only environment variables?

Tags: windows, windows-10, environment-variables

### 1. Summary

Today I migrate to Windows 10 64-bit. I want to change my system and user environment variables, but I can not change some variables.

---

### 2. Reasons

1. If in future I install other operation system to my current system drive, I must to delete all data from my system drive. I don't want it, and I want that my data to write in another partition.
2. In my system drive I have only 100 free GB, but in another partition I have 600 free GB. I use many programs, and, perhaps, my system drive will be quickly filled.

---

### 3. Environment variables

Environment variables, that I want to change:

[image: Env]

- `ALLUSERPROFILE`,
- `ProgramData`,
- `ProgramFiles`,
- `ProgramFiles(x86)`,
- `APPDATA`,
- `USERPROFILE`.

I want to change `C:\ProgramData` to `D:\ProgramData`, `C:\Program Files (x86`) to `D:\Program Files (x86)` and so on.

---

### 4. Not helped

1. I try to edit these variables, use [**Rapid Environment Editor**](https://www.rapidee.com/en/about) and [**Eveditor**](http://eveditor.com/) programs, but I have not success.
2. I find in Google only solutions, where I must manually edit my registry. For example, solution for [**Program Files**](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-default-program-files-directory-windows) and [**AppData**](http://www.tweaklibrary.com/System/Application-Path/71/Change-default-location-of-the-%E2%80%9CApplication-Data%E2%80%9D-folder/10471/) variables.

---

### 5. Questions

1. Is it a bad practice - change locations for environment variables? If yes, what is the best practice?
2. May I edit all my read-only variables without manually registry editing? Is there tweaks or applications?

---

### 6. Do not offer

1. Please, do not offer, how I can change editable environment variables, for example, `PATH` or `TEMP`.
2. Yes, I know about symlinks.

Comment: How you move those folders is well documented.  You have to edit the registry (and do other things) in order to do that.  If you are not willing to edit the register then it cannot be done.

Comment: The keys `ProgramFilesDir` and `ProgramFilesDir (x86)` must be changed in the registry.  You have to create a symbolic link to move AppData and any user profile that exists on the system.  This includes the default user profile.  Since you don't want to hear symbolic links I won't submit an answer.  It is worth pointing out none of these changes are supported by Microsoft, and they WILL cause you problems, when the next feature release (1703) is released.  If you move the user profile you move AppData also, since AppData, is stored within the user's profile directory

Comment: @Ramhound, `Since you don't want to hear symbolic links` - no, if symbolic links is the best practice, I will be used it. Symlinks creating for each folder from environment variable is the best solution for my problem? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered the implications of modifying those variables? As for "using many programs" you could just specify and alternate path during installation. Modifying the `ProgramFiles` e.g. would mean you would need to move everything that is already in that folder to the new location as well.

Comment: @Seth, `Have you considered the implications of modifying those variables?` - I asked the community of Super User, is it a bad practice; `As for "using many programs" you could just specify and alternate path during installation.` - I install almost all 150+ my programs via Chocolatey package manager use 2 command in command line, manually installation all programs takes a lot of  time.

Comment: `Modifying the ProgramFiles e.g. would mean you would need to move everything that is already in that folder to the new location as well.` - I just install my Windows 64-bit and I not yet install my programs in `Program Files` directory. Thanks.

Comment: Yes but there are already file and shared files in that directory and certain components could be referencing to `ProgramFiles` in order to find them. As such you should move or duplicate those files to where you ever move the variable to. (Link [1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/933700), [2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/949977) [3 Supported](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275(v=ws.11).aspx)) Did you try to lookup whenever you can change the install path? In addition have a look at the size, maybe moving the biggest installations would be sufficient.